# Form results immediately overwritten with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, forms

I'm trying to create a simple for that replaces keywords in a document, but I'm struggling with the basic input.

Essentially, I've used jQuery's ajax function to pull in the contents of a Google spreadsheet which I then want to use as a source for keywords to change.

I've then tried to connect an HTML up to jQuery so someone could paste in some text on which to do the work.

The problem is that as soon as I paste in some copy and then click submit, it appears briefly and then the HTML resets. What have I done wrong?

You can find the code here: http://jsbin.com/IMIwabe/1/edit?html,console,output

```
<title>Test Form</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
    #results_box {
        border: red 5px solid;
                }

    #place {
        border: #cccccc 1px solid;

    }           
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var json_source = "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/0ApL1zT2P00q5dG1wOUMzSlNVV3VRV2pwQ2Fnbmt3M0E/od7/public/basic?alt=json";
    var json_data = $.ajax({

        dataType: 'jsonp',
        url: json_source,
        success: function(data){
            //for (i=0; i<data.feed.entry.length; i++){
            //  $('#results_box').append(data.feed.entry[i].title['$t']);
            //} 
            json_data = data.feed.entry;
            return json_data;

        },      

        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){ 
                        $('#results_box').html('<h2>Something went wrong!</h2><p><b>' + textStatus  + '</b> ' + errorThrown  + '</p>');
        }
    }); 

    $(':submit').click(function(){
        //function convert text box postcode into lat long
        if ($('#place').val() !=''){
            var copy_string = $('#place').val();
            $('#results_box').html(copy_string);
        }  

    }); 

});//document ready end 
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="query_box" class="panel">  
  <form id="form_submit"><h4>Copy to process:</h4>
    <textarea id="place"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" />

  </form>
</div>
<div id="results_box" >Results will appear here</div>  
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why haven't you just put the code in the question?

Comment: I thought it was too much to place, and I couldn't work out which bits to highlight. I'll add it now. Sorry.

Comment: A fiddle or jsbin is always useful but the question should also always include the code. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code)

Comment: I'll remember that in future. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return false from your submit to prevent the submit from actually firing. Your click event is firing but then the form is getting submitted, resetting the page.

```
$(':submit').click(function(){
    //function convert text box postcode into lat long
    if ($('#place').val() !=''){
        var copy_string = $('#place').val();
        $('#results_box').html(copy_string);
    }  
    return false;
});
```

You could also use `preventDefault` but return false does effectively the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

You should prevent default in your click event because GO is submit button and it will try to submit entire form:

```
$(':submit').click(function(event){
    //function convert text box postcode into lat long
    if ($('#place').val() !=''){
        var copy_string = $('#place').val();
        $('#results_box').html(copy_string);
         event.preventDefault();
    }  

});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$('#te').click(function(){
            //function convert text box postcode into lat long
            if ($('#place').val() !=''){
                var copy_string = $('#place').val();
                $('#results_box').html(copy_string);
            }  

        }); 

    });//document ready end 
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="query_box" class="panel">  
      <form ><h4>Copy to process:</h4>
        <textarea id="place"></textarea>
        <input id="te" type="button" value="Go" />

      </form>
    </div>
    <div id="results_box" >Results will appear here</div>  
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
$(':submit').click(function(){
            //function convert text box postcode into lat long
            if ($('#place').val() !=''){
                var copy_string = $('#place').val();
                $('#results_box').html(copy_string);
            }  

        });
```

To something like that

```
<input type="submit" value="Go" onclick = "convertTextBox(); return false;"/>
```

And in your js :

```
function convertTextBox(){
                //function convert text box postcode into lat long
                if ($('#place').val() !=''){
                    var copy_string = $('#place').val();
                    $('#results_box').html(copy_string);
                }  

            });
```

See the return false after the call of the `convertTextBox()` function, it prevents your form from being really submitted, reloading the webpage with form parameters.

Comment: Where's the return false?